# fluent bit giving 400 with elastic search - contains an unknown parameter [_type]"},"status":400

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes-pod, fluent

[2022/04/17 14:48:10] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1650206880.316011791.flb', retry in 16 seconds: task_id=4, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
[2022/04/17 14:48:10] [error] [output:es:es.0] HTTP status=400 URI=/_bulk, response:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"},"status":400}

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by 3 steps, Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72690157/fluentd-http-status-400-uri-bulk-response/76100062#76100062)

Answer (score 13):

Add the following to the output-es.conf file.

Suppress_Type_Name On