# Fluentd HTTP status=400 URI=/_bulk, response:

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

i wan't to send pod log to ELK, buat after deploying fluentd i get Error, i got from tutorial Official Fluentd documentation

EKS Version 1.22

i put Suppress_Type_Name On, it's not solved this issue

```
[2022/06/20 16:23:07] [error] [output:es:es.0] HTTP status=400 URI=/_bulk, response:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Action/metadata line [1] contains an unknown parameter [_type]"},"status":400}
```

my configmap

```
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020

    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf

  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10

  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off

  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format On
        Replace_Dots    On
        Retry_Limit     False
```

Comment: do you have any news on your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by these 3 steps,

step 1. You need to update your fluentbit image to latest

> ```
>     image: fluent/fluent-bit:2.1.1
> ```

You can get the deployment file from [here](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.5/installation/kubernetes)

step 2: Add "Suppress_Type_Name On" to output-elasticsearch.conf

```
  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           *
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        HTTP_User       ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER}
        HTTP_Passwd     ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
        Logstash_Format On
        Replace_Dots    On
        Retry_Limit     False
        Suppress_Type_Name On
```

Step 3. Delete the fluentbit pods and reapply it

```
kubectl delete -f fluentbit-ds.yaml
kubectl apply -f fluentbit-ds.yaml
```